# Regex split string in qt

Tags: regex, qt

So, I'm writting app in Qt and I need to split a string into operators and variables like this:
`a&&b||!c` --> vars `["a", "b", "c"]` and operators `["&&", "||", "!"]`.

I wrote this:
to get list of vars:

```
QRegExp rx("[&|!]+");
QStringList vars = exp.split(rx, QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

for operators, I tried this one:

```
QRegExp oprx("[a-z]");
QStringList operators = exp.split(oprx, QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

but it gives last operand like "||!".Can you help me with a pattern for spliting operators.

Comment: Try to add backslash before "|", because this character in regex means "OR".

Comment: Or even two backslashes to represent backslash itself in a C string.

Comment: Can you use `QRegularExpression`? If yes, you may just use `"\\b[_A-Za-z]\\w*|[^\\w\\s]+"` and use matching rather than splitting.